# Which side of a PWM MOSFET should an inductor go on?

Tags: mosfet, inductor

I have a power supply circuit that needs to supply bursts of power at 5A, 8V but only 1/4-1/8 of the time (using PWM). I wanted to smooth the current draw out on the actual source of the power, a large battery, and I figured an inductor would be able to average out the 5A current draw so that the actual current draw on the battery would be more around 1A or less. I was wondering which side of the MOSFET I'm using to control the PWM I should put the inductor on, whether to put it between the MOSFET and the battery or the MOSFET and the load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is effectively a buck converter - with the caution that by smoothing full current pulses you may get a result that you do not expect. To do this properly you need to adjust the PWM cycle so that the output current is what you want. In this case you want to monitor for 1A or less (which you specify) and adjust accordingly.

See diagram below. Note that if you are interrupting the supply to the inductor then ou **must** also provide a "freewheel" diode as shown to provide a path for the continued current. This needs to be rated at the mean output current and be a fast enough device to handle the switching frequency.

[image]

[Diagram from here](http://elsoc.wikia.com/wiki/Buck_Converter)

Comment or add to the question (and let us know you have done so in a comment) if more information is wanted.

The question could be improved. Knowing more about what you are trying to do and what equipment is involved will help us give you a better answer. What is the load? What is the source and why are you wanting to reduce the current? What is the output voltage intended to be? etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not following all the hand waving, but if you want to smooth out current to the battery, put the inductorin series with the battery.  However, that can cause some problems of its own.  For one thing, it will make the impedance of the battery appear high at high frequencies.  You need to put a cap on the circuit side of the inductor to bring the impedance down at high frequencies.  Put another way, the cap will supply the short term changes in current while the battery thru the inductor catches up.  After all, the inductor's job is to smooth out the battery current, but your circuit will still need current when it needs it.